# Postgres syntax error when using 'like' in single quote

Tags: sql, postgresql, yii, syntax-error

I am getting a syntax error in a PostgreSQL query. I am working on a project developed in `YII1`, I am getting an error

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42601]:
>   Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "s" LINE 1: ...OT NULL
>   AND sub_heading like '%Women and Children's Voices%'.

As you can see above, I am using the `like` operator in single quotes, and in the string there is another single quote (`Children's`). So PostgreSQL is throwing me an error. Please provide me a solution to escape the string.

Comment: So where your query? Just show the error not helping..

Comment: `'%Women and Children''s Voices%'`. Or possibly a backslash instead of doubled quotes; I don't remember which one postgres prefers.

Comment: Hi @Shawn, thanks for your reply, I did same thing and it works, I replaced single quote with double and it works

Answer (score 1):

You can escape a single quote in a string by using another single quote (i.e., `''` instead of `'`. Note that these are two `'` characters, not a single `"` character):

```
sub_heading LIKE '%Women and Children''s Voices%'
-- Here -----------------------------^
```

Comment: Hi @Mureinik, thanks for your answer, Actually value **Women and Children** was coming from a variable, so I can't change it in the query so I replaced the single quote with double quotes using PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`format`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) function to construct the SQL statement, using the `%L` placeholder for the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by replacing the single quote with double quotes using PHP. Here is the code
There is a variable **$var** with value `Women and Children's Voices`. I replace that single quote using the str_replace() function.
`$var = str_replace("'", "''", $var);`

Comment: Why are you not using placeholders? Doing this yourself is madness.